# blood investigation probability

Tags: probability

A large number $N$ of people are subjected to a blood investigation. This investigation can be organized in two
ways.

$(1)$ The blood of each person is investigated separately. In this case $N$ analyses are needed.

$(2)$ The blood of $k$ people are mixed and the mixture is analysed. If the result is negative, then this single analysis is sufficient for $k$ persons.
But if it is positive, then the blood of each one must be subsequently investigated separately, and in toto for $k$ people, $k + 1$ analysis are needed. It is assumed that the probability of a positive result ($p$) is the same for all people and that the results of the analysis are independent in the probabilistic sense.

• What is the probability that the analysis of the mixed blood of $k$ people is positive?

• What is the expectation of the number of analysis necessary in the second method of testing?

• For what $k$ is the minimum expected number of necessary analysis obtained?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question.

> What is the probability that the analysis of the mixed blood of $k$ people is positive?

Let $X_i = 1$ iff the $i$-th person is positive and $X_i=0$ otherwise. We have
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{mixed blood of $k$ people is positive}) \ = \ \mathbb{P}(X_1 \ \text{or } \ X_2 \ \text{or} \ \dots \ \text{or} \ X_k \ \text{is} \ 1)$$
$$= \ 1-\mathbb{P}(X_1, \dots, X_k \ \text{are all} \ 0 ) \ = \ 1-(1-p)^k.$$

> What is the expectation of the number of analysis necessary in the second method of testing?

Let as assume that $k$ is a divisor of $N$, i.e. $N=k\cdot m$. Then the answer is
$$m\cdot \Big(\text{expected number of tests needed to check a group of $k$ people}\Big)$$
$$= \ m\cdot\Big[1\cdot(1-p)^k \ + \ (k+1)\cdot\Big(1-(1-p)^k\Big)\Big].  $$

I will live You with further calculations. Please note, that the independence assumption is crucial.